# css layout grid container center

Tags: html, css

I tried to make layout responsive base on window width than container update width use window width`100%` divide grid width`100px` than align center`margin: 0 auto`.
but when I use css `clac` it's not work `100%/100px` , how to solve it is it possible only use css without js to make it

http://jsfiddle.net/3pvk0ooh/

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="grid">grid</div>
    <div class="grid">grid</div>
    <div class="grid">grid</div>
</div>

.container {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(100%/100px);
}
.grid {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the first value in `calc()` is the percentage and the second value is a numeric number, meaning, you cannot divide by pixels. i.e. `calc(100% / 7)` is correct, `calc(100% / 7px)` is incorrect.

This won't fix your problem, however, according to this site: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ - There must be spaces surrounding the math operator.

Explanation:

> Division. The right-hand side must be a `<number>`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Please note the backwards compatibility of the `calc` function: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Thanks for reply. I knew it can be something like `calc(100% + 100px)` but I can't find any document said cannot divide by pixels (do you?) so thats why i give a try

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Update your css like this:

```
.container {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(100%/100px);
    display: table;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float : left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
}
```

and the results you can see here: [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/paydjo/vL20aL33/)

Hope that helps !

Comment: when you resize the window width then those grid not in center